# The vowel in the definite article "the" when followed by a consonant

Tags: definite-article, pronunciation

I am a bit confused about how to practically pronounce the vowel in the definite article "the" when  followed by a consonant. In theory, it should be a [schwa](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the).

However, I have a feeling like, in many practical situations, the vowel is pronounced more like a "short e" (as in "bed") rather than a schwa. At least, that gets very close to a short e.

As an example, you can try having Google Translate pronounce the three-word phrase "**the**refore, **the** cat". It is not only Google Translate that pronounces it this way. I've heard many native speakers similarly pronounce the vowel in the definite article "the", when followed by a consonant, very similar to a short "e" if not identical to it.

Is it fair to say that in spoken English it is ok to pronounce the vowel in "the" when followed by a consonant *very similar* to a short "e"?

Comment: All I hear is a very short indistinct vowel,  the quality of the vowel isn't very important.  It is fairly central (not [i:])  I don't hear a distinct [e] any other particular vowel.

Comment: It's a regular schwa. I had a Spanish-speaker lecturer in philosophy at a very prestigious UK university as a student. Their speech was really distracting and painful to listen to precisely because they pronounced *the* as /ðe/. It's one of the most common words in the English language. Please, please do NOT do this, unless you want to distract your listener with your strange and uncomfortable pronunciation.

Comment: @JamesK Thank you for your response. I'll try to think about your comment. So you are saying that the vowel in "therefore" is not central whereas the vowel in "the" is?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thank you for your response and sorry about the negative experience you had. I wonder if you hear significantly different vowel sounds when you listen to Google Translate saying the phrase "therefore, the cat"? I think Google Translate speaks in standard American accent or at least something close enough.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. BTW, you said, it is a "regular" schwa. I wonder if there exist more than one type of schwa. If so, can please list them all?

Comment: One reason for difference is that my google might not be your google.  My google has a British accent, but yours seems to have an American accent.  So what I hear and what you hear must be different.

Comment: @JamesK I think it is not just Google. I tried listening to the "example" section of the entry for "the" in the [Longman] (https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the) dictionary. The examples there have an audio recording which seems to be in British accent. I feel like the vowel in the examples where "the" is followed by a consonant is not too different from a short e. (Compare it, for example, to the schwa used in the word "acquire" which is clearly not a short e.)

Comment: @Jeff:  in Google's pronunciation of *therefore, the cat*, and in the *Longman* dictionary's pronunciation of *the*, I clearly hear schwas (*therefore* contains a different vowel). I expect the way these vowels are pronounced in your first language is confusing you.

Comment: It's a matter of context and emphasis: I'm telling you that I saw *the* cat come over the wall a moment ago. /ði/ ("thee,")//Also: I'm telling you that I saw *the* cat come over the wall a moment ago. /ðə/ ("thuh"). *This is beyond the rule for words starting with consonants or vowels*. Vowels need /ði/ ("thee,") But consonants can take both depending on emphasis. When we use /ði/ ("thee")  with a consonant, we're being emphatic.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a lot of regional variation; in Yorkshire for example you might enquire about a missing feline with a sentence that would be written “where’s t’ cat?” But is pronounced “where’s (gets ready to say ‘t’ but doesn’t) cat”.  Around the country you’ll find almost any short vowel sound being used in place of the ‘e’, so unless you’re trying to imitate a particular dialect it’s safe to use whatever feels most comfortable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. At present, I am trying to master the "standard American accent". Any suggestions for this choice specifically?

Comment: That’s not my area of expertise :-)

Comment: t' can be spoken at times, but [spelling is inconsistent](https://milnersblog.com/tag/on-ilkley-moor-bar-tat-song-lyrics/)

Answer (score 0):

It is typically pronounced with a schwa; that's how I hear the Google Translate version. More specifically, in such contexts it is generally pronounced as a *weak form,* [as Geoff Lindsey helpfully explains.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EaXYas58_kc) Weak forms are spoken very rapidly in ways that can make it hard to hear the underlying vowel sound. They essentially become short prefixes attached to the word after them (see [another Geoff Lindsey video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=qfCsiF80TX0)).